# chsh is not working in win10 sub linux

Tags: shell, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to change my shell to zsh under windows 10's sub linux. Everywhere I google says, I should use

```
chsh /bin/zsh
```

But after log out and log in, the shell is still bash.

However, `vi /etc/passwd` shows that

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:
syslog:x:101:104::/home/syslog:/bin/false
messagebus:x:102:106::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
landscape:x:103:109::/var/lib/landscape:/bin/false
sshd:x:104:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
pollinate:x:105:1::/var/cache/pollinate:/bin/false
qq:x:1000:1000:"",,,:/home/qq:/bin/zsh
colord:x:106:112:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
```

Why is chsh not working in win10's bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they call it "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" they really mean it - the shortcut just runs the Bash executable directly.

If you access the system some other way (over SSH, or by running `login` or a display manager) then it will read `/etc/passwd` as usual.

More simply, you can edit your `.bashrc` to fake it up. Add:

```
if [ -t 1 ]
then
   exec zsh
fi
```

to the end.

You can also create new Windows shortcuts (or modify your existing ones) that spawn something else - `bash.exe -c /usr/bin/zsh` should work well enough too.

There is [a bug reported about this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/846). I don't think it's a high priority (and it's not *really* a bug), but any of these workarounds will get you pretty close.

Comment: By the way, what is `if [ -t 1 ]`? I googled and find  "-t FD : True if FD is opened on a terminal." What does it mean?

Comment: 1 is standard output, so it checks whether output is a terminal. The test probably isn't necessary, actually - it's mainly useful with SSH.